# column is there, but I receive: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: requestor.birthyear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a meetings table, which has a requestor (user) with an attribute birthyear.

In the terminal I can do Meeting.find(1).requestor.birthyear

But in the meeting controller, it says `no such column: requestor.birthyear`

I tried adding something like `users_attributes: [:birthyear]` in the meetings_params, but it didn't make any difference.

What am I missing?

Here are the full files:
meeting controller

```
def community
  if current_user.birthyear != nil
    @meeting_requests = Meeting.where('meeting_time >= ? AND requestee_id IS ? AND status = ? AND (requestor.birthyear <= ? AND requestor.birthyear >= ?)', Date.today, nil, "Active", current_user.birthyear + 10, current_user.birthyear - 10).order('meeting_time asc')
  end
end
```

meeting model

```
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :requestee, class_name: "User"
end
```

error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: requestor.birthyear: SELECT "meetings".* FROM "meetings" WHERE (meeting_time >= '2017-03-06' AND requestee_id IS NULL AND status = 'Active' AND (requestor.birthyear <= 1944 AND requestor.birthyear >= 1924)) ORDER BY meeting_time asc
```

Let me know if you need anything further - thank in advance!

UPDATE

trying to join the tables in the query, but not too knowledgeable on that. I'm trying:

```
@meeting_requests = Meeting.where('meeting_time >= ? AND requestee_id IS ? AND status = ? ', Date.today, nil, "Active").order('meeting_time asc').joins("INNER JOIN users on requestor.birthyear >= current_user.birthyear + 10")
```

but get:

`ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: status: SELECT "meetings".* FROM "meetings" INNER JOIN users on requestor.birthyear >= current_user.birthyear + 10 WHERE (meeting_time >= '2017-03-07' AND requestee_id IS NULL AND status = 'Active' ) ORDER BY meeting_time asc):`

---

*****UPDATE*****
I posted another question to get the syntax. If it helps anyone:
[Rails: Two 'where' queries - each works individually, but not together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654118/rails-two-where-queries-each-works-individually-but-not-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requestor` and `requestee` are Rails associations. This means that Rails understands how to get to `requestor` from a Meeting...

However - your database does not know what a `requestor` is. So you can't put it into the string-part of a SQL-query like you have done here:

```
 AND (requestor.birthyear <= ? AND requestor.birthyear >= ?)'
```

Instead you will need to use joins to add these to your query, then figure out how rails names them in order to access the columns from them.

Comment: If this is the case, why can I do it in the terminal, and it understands what I'm saying, but not in the controller? I'm calling the same DB. Also - how can I do it. I already have the DB set up this way, so redo the entire DB with join tables is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: what exactly are you doing in the terminal?

Comment: " already have the DB set up this way, so redo the entire DB with join tables is not an option unfortunately." oops, this is not what I'm suggesting... my mistake for wording it as join-tables... I meant adding the tables as joins to your query.

Comment: I can do something like Meeting.find(1).requestor.birthyear and it gives me the user's birthyear. So, I figured I could query the same way

Comment: `Meeting.find(1).requestor.birthyear` but this is what I meant by *Rails* understanding what a `requestor` is... that is ruby code you've just written. But what you enter into the string that you pass to `where` goes directly to the database... it's not ruby... it will be SQL only

Comment: I updated the question. I'm trying to join, as suggested, but am not totally sure how. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: That's a different error ;) `ambiguous column name: status: ` means that there is a status column in more than one table - eg meeting vs user table - or possibly in this case, you are joining the users table... onto another version of the users table - so you could be getting the status from the requestor user, or from the requestee table. Whichever it is... you now need to be specific *which* table you're getting status from eg `meetings.status` vs `requestor.status`