# Rails: Two 'where' queries - each works individually, but not together

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I want to write something like:

```
@meeting_requests = Meeting.where('meeting_time >= ? AND requestee_id IS ? 
                                   AND status = ?', Date.today, nil, "Active")
                           .joins(:requestor)
                           .where('birthyear >= ? AND birthyear <= ?',
                                  current_user.birthyear - 10, 
                                  current_user.birthyear + 10 )
```

This works:

```
@meeting_requests = Meeting.where('meeting_time >= ? AND requestee_id IS ? 
                                   AND status = ?', Date.today, nil, "Active")
```

And this works:

```
@meeting_requests = Meeting.joins(:requestor)
                           .where('birthyear >= ? AND birthyear <= ?',
                                   current_user.birthyear - 10,
                                   current_user.birthyear + 10 )
```

And something like this works:

```
Meeting.joins(:requestor).where('birthyear > ?', 1900).where(status: "Active")
```

but I need to do a greater than query on the meeting_time, so I need to write it as a string I think?

But together both sql queries produce an error of: `ambiguous column name: status: SELECT`

I feel like I'm so close... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a message that appears when it is not clear which table the column comes from. This should work:

```
...rest_of_statement.where('meetings.status' => 'Active')
```

Comment: Wow... that worked. Why would it know meeting_time and requestee_id are both associated to meetings, but not status? I don't see the difference between those attributes. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Maybe there is a `status` field in `requestors` table? That should be a reason, because by joining you are firing a select statement that references both tables. So, by requesting `status` it is not clear if you mean `requestors.status` or `meetings.status`

Comment: Oh interesting! Yes - the user has a status field, and requestor is a foreign key for user. Mystery solved... thank you so much!!